# My microphone recording volume automatically changes

Tags: skype, alsa, microphone, volume-control, audio-jack

Whenever I do talk on Skype I can watch with alsamixer, how the setting: Internal reduces its volume.

Sadly the volume goes so much down, that I get muted. I do have to constantly watch my recording volume and adjust it. Sometimes people hang up on phone if they do not hear me for 1-2 seconds.

How can I set the volume to a fixed one?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Skype - Options - Sound devices - turn off "Allow Skype to automatically adjust my mixer levels"

Comment: Thanks, i did not know that skype is the issue.
If in the next calls tested successful I will mark your answer as correct

Comment: If not, drop a comment!  ;-)